# How to watch for data change in json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to update my view each time there is data change in json file without manually refreshing page.
I using the following method to do some data polling. Here is my service file to get $http

```
.service('employees', function ($http) {
    this.getEmployees = function() {
      return $http.get( './data/employee.json' );
    };
```

This is my controller

```
.controller('The3Ctrl', function ($scope, employees, $interval) {
   var _this = this;
  $scope.getData = function() {
    employees.getEmployees().then(function(response){
        _this.items = response.data;
        $scope.items = _this.items;
    });
  }
  $scope.getData();

  $interval(function(){
    $scope.getData();
  }, 10000);
```

With this the getData function is triggered every 10 seconds. However, What I want is for the function to only be triggered if there is a change in data (data.json) file. If there is no data change, it's useless for the function to be triggered.

Comment: The ability to watch a file for changes is not built into Angular, so what you are wanting to do would likely require the Angular application to communicate with another application/process that can watch system files and notify it to update. Can you provide a bit of background around the overall process (how are the files updated, your operating system, ...)?

Answer (score 0):

What do you refer with "change" or what is the problem When the view doesnt update
you can use `$scope.$apply();`
or you can detect a change with

```
$scope.$watch('element', function () {
    console.error('element' + element + ' changes');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**If the file is inside the App:**

```
 scope.$watch('Data', function(newValue, oldValue) {
 if (newValue){

   }
  });
```

**If the file is on Server:**

You can achieve this through polling, Polling is done with old callbacks, you can call them repeatedly without need to create new instance of the promise. It works like timer, here is the sample

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);    
    app.controller("The3Ctrl", ["$scope","$http","$timeout",
        function($scope, $http,$timeout) {
        var nextPolling;
        var pollingInterval = 10000; // 10 seconds
        var _polling = function ()
        {
            $http.get('./data/employee.json')
                .success(function(data) {$scope.items = data;})
                .error(function(data) {console.log('error');})
                .finally(function(){ nextPolling = $timeout(_polling, pollingInterval); });
        };

        _polling();

        $scope.$on('$destroy', function (){
            if (nextPolling){
                $timeout.cancel(nextPolling);
            }
        });


    }]);
```

Working [`App`](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ChZft1T9d3PdLRkmRhS?p=preview)

Comment: can you do som explaining?

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj hope you got it now

Comment: The thing here is, this works but I don't see any difference from my solution as it updates every second even without data change. I want it to update only when there is data change.

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj is your data on server or inside the same folder

Comment: Inside thesame folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I am new in Angular kind of struggling.  How do i get the newValue and oldValues given that am using promise?

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj Then its easy, let me create a sample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118931/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-obasi-obeny-oj).